# Creating a NPM package like [name]/[second_name] ? name can only contain URL-friendly characters. where is the "[second_name]" added?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to create a NPM package, can someone explain how to add a package to something after the slash?

So for example, if you create a package, you use:

```
npm init
```

then when you fill out the name, it constantly gives an error saying, name can only contain URL-friendly characters if I incldue a "/" in it when selecting the name.

If I change the NPM name, say I make it:

> Testname

I can upload it to NPM package repository.

But If I add

> Testname/testname2

It will say the name contains illegal characters. You cannot use anything with a "/" in the name.

So can someone please explain to me, how does the "/testname2" get added to a NPM package name? I have searched google for hours trying to find it.

The best I could find was here: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules

For "scoped modules" you can add

```
npm init --scope=@scope-name
```

via https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes

However, when I run this, it does not change the package.json file. The file still looks identical to to other one with no reference to the "scoped" name of the parent file.

Is whatever is after the "/" a file within the parent directory?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-an-organization

Answer (score 1):

NPM packages can only contain alphanumeric characters. The “nested” package names you see (i.e. `@bugsnag/plugin-vue`) are packages that live within an NPM organization. So the aforementioned is a package named `plugin-vue` that lives within an organization named `@bugsnag`. You can’t have arbitrary nesting in package names like `foo/bar`.

Comment: thanks... so for your example /plugin-vue, how do you actually set that up like that ? like what is it called to bild a packaged within an NPM organization ? so it sounds like first, I need to turn my package into an organization ? I have seen you can do that